# Newly Added Column is not Appearing in Synonym

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS` under the `XX` schema.
It has an existing `SYNONYM` to `AA` schema.

I am currently logged in as `AA` and I wanted to add a column to `YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS` and executed the below command just fine

```
alter table XX.YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS
add (USER_DEFINED_FISC_CLASS VARCHAR2(30));
```

> Table XX.YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS altered.

I tried to select the Column from the Table using the simple query below

```
select  USER_DEFINED_FISC_CLASS
from    YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS;
```

But I surprisingly got this error:

> ORA-00904: "USER_DEFINED_FISC_CLASS": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 9

I thought I just missed altering the table, so I re-ran the `ALTER` script again, but got this error instead:

> Error starting at line : 4 in command - alter table
>   XX.YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS add (USER_DEFINED_FISC_CLASS VARCHAR2(30))
>   Error report - ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table
>   01430. 00000 -  "column being added already exists in table"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I checked the Object Definition and sure enough, I found the new column there:

[image]

But when I query all the columns from the Table, I still can't see it:

```
select  *
from    YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS;
```

[image]

However, when I query using the `XX` schema prefix, I'm able to see the column:

```
select  *
from    XX.YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS;
```

[image]

Why isn't the synonym picking up the newly-added column?

Comment: Did you double check you're doing the `alter` and the `select` in the same database?

Comment: yes, it's actually the same session @HoneyBadger

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I added more information. it seems when i query using the schema, the column appears.

Comment: Do you happen to have a table or a view called YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS where you are querying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was caused by this "[Edition-Based Redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS99923)" thing that Oracle recently introduced for 12c.

Upon further investigation, what happened was:

The Table `XX.XX_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS` has a Editionable view named `XX_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS#` that only selects a certain number of columns.

Now, the View `XX_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS#` has a SYNONYM named `XX_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS` under the schema `AA`, hence the confusion on the Table having a SYNONYM of the same name.

To resolve this, i modified the view `XX_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS#` and added the new column and successfully recompiled it.

Once this was done, the synonym now shows the newly-added column and I was able to compile the stored procedure successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could be having a table or a view called YY_ZZ_VAT_TRX_DETAILS or a private synonym that points to another table?.

In oracle the preference while querying is

1)objects_in same schema 
2)private synonym
3)public synonym

Comment: thanks for your input, i was able to resolve it. please see my answer below.